# One folder, two KML files

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

We want to display two KML files into the Google Earth plugin.  KML 1 will have Folder 1, containing placemarks.  KML 2, will have more placemarks that belong under Folder 1.  Does KML/Google Earth support that?  The reason for two KML’s is that we want to display KML 1 before we finish generating KML 2.  Actually, we may have several KML files...

Comment: Will you please be more specific on this so that we can help

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are a number of ways to do this.

One simple way would be to create `Folder 1` via the api rather than via KML.
Then when you load your KML files you can simply append them to the folder you created
For example.

```
var folder = ge.createFolder("folder1");
google.earth.fetchKml(ge, "your.kml", function(kml) {
  if(kml) {
    folder.appendChild(kml);
  }
});
```

If you did want or need to load `Folder 1` via KML you could simply target it via `getElementByUrl` and then append any further KML to it.

```
var folder = ge.getElementByUrl("your.kml#folder1");
google.earth.fetchKml(ge, "more.kml", function(kml) {
  if(kml) {
    folder.appendChild(kml);
  }
});
```

Finally, the KML `NetworkLink` and `NetworkLinkControl` elements could be used to link the files together - allowing you to update your data dynamically solely via KML...but without more information on your setup it is hard to offer any specific solutions in this regard.